# Clojure reloaded workflow without using library like Component?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, http-kit

So I have a simple webapp that has a main method that starts an http server. 
The dev setup that I want to achieve is basically something like using lein auto, but I want to stop and start my server and reload namespaces automatically on file change. 
This seems like something that should be straightforward and easy, but so far I haven't found any lein plugins or other ways to really achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is what I was looking for, a combination of [tools.namespace](https://github.com/clojure/tools.namespace) and [wrap-reload](https://ring-clojure.github.io/ring/ring.middleware.reload.html).

Here's what I came up with:

```
(ns your-project.core
  (:require [clojure.tools.namespace.repl :as tn]
            [org.httpkit.server :as http]
            [ring.middleware.reload :refer [wrap-reload]]
            [compojure.core :refer [defroutes GET]]

(defroutes create-app []
  (GET "/" [] (fn [req] "hello world")

(defonce server (atom nil))

(defn start []
  (let [app (create-app)]
    (reset! server (http/run-server (wrap-reload app) {:port 3000}))
    (println (str "Listening on port " 3000))))

(defn stop []
  (when @server
    (@server :timeout 100)
    (reset! server nil)))

(defn restart []
  (stop)
  (tn/refresh :after 'your-project.core/start))
```

Comment: Yep, this looks exactly like what I'm looking for. Thanks

Comment: shouldnt you re-load it only in dev mode ?

Comment: Yeah you’re right, I kind of expanded on this in my latest project, it’s far from perfect, but it attempts to distinguish between prod and dev https://github.com/swlkr/coast/blob/master/src/coast/server.clj